# OpenCV use with Xbox One Kinect

Tags: opencv, kinect, rgb, kinect-sdk, depth

I'm looking to use the Xbox One Kinect with OpenCV, and I'm having a hard time finding any examples of such. I see tons of projects that implement the previous versions of the Kinect. Is it possible to open the RGB and Depth stream from the Xbox One Kinect using OpenCV and process that data and how? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you tell what did you try?

Comment: also, seems like this guy had it working: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25788545/kinect-for-windows-v2-depth-to-color-image-misalignment

Comment: I googled around looking for any project using the new Xbox one Kinect with openCV. Hadn't found much of anything.

Comment: It says it uses the Xbox Kinect for windows v2, not the Xbox one Kinect. (I've already seen that in my search)

Comment: Did you try? they look the same :)