# kinect one calibration / overlay rgb and depth images with opencv

Tags: opencv, kinect, rgb, depth, calibration

I’m working on a project where I will need to use Kinect One, I do not have that much experience with that kind of sensors(neither this new one nor with old kinect). Therefore I started playing around with it and I successfully managed to acquire images using the Kinect SDK v2.0 and opencv. Now what I would like to do is to overlay the two views from the rgb sensor and the ir/depth sensor in order to create a rgb-d image. Kinect SDK provides a class for that reason, named CoordinateMapper, but does not provide sufficient results (speed & quality) plus I am facing the problem that @api55 describes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25788545). Therefore I would like to try and manually do it, plus for learning reasons. The color camera has a full HD resolution (1920x1080 pixel) and the depth/infrared image is 512x424 pixel, respectively. Plus the two sensors have different aspect ratio. Searching around I found out that the proper way is first to calibrate the two sensors and then apply any mapping between the two views.

I am gonna be using opencv for both calibration and mapping procedures. For the calibration I noticed that people here and in general propose that it would be better if I first individually calibrate the two sensors using the `calibrate()` function and then use the extracted cameraMatrix/intrinsic and distortion coefficients/distCoeffs values to the `stereoCalibrate()` function in order to obtain the rotation(R) and translation(T) matrices plus some others, e.g. R1,R2,P1,P2,Q,etc..., needed later for the mapping. Using an asymmetric circles grid pattern I managed to calibrate individually each sensor in its initial resolution and aspect ratio obtaining a reprojection error, rms of 0.3 and 0.1 for rgb and ir sensors respectively. Passing the extracted values to the `stereoCalibrate()` with `CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS` and `CV_CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC` I managed to obtain R and T matrices with a reprojection error, rms = ~0.4 which seems also to be good.

---

**Question 1**

However before I continue, here I have a question the `stereoCalibrate()` has a parameter about the image size, I used the size from the ir camera since later on I would like to use this resolution in order to map the two views. On the other hand I read somewhere that it does not play any role since it is only useful for initialization in intrinsic camera calibration (according to openCV documentation), which is not used if `stereoCalibrate()` is called with parameter `CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC` is that correct? Moreover, do you think that I should resize the high resolution camera to the size of the smaller one since I am gonna use the latter one later for the mapping. I guess I will need to apply some cropping as well due to the different aspect ration, right? or it is not necessary.

---

Continuing without resizing and cropping at the end I managed to obtain all the necessary information needed for the undistortion and rectification from the `stereoRectify()` function. So, I have successfully obtained the cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q matrices. Trying now to undistort/rectify and remap the two view in their initial sizes I obtained the following result:

[image]
[image]

which seems to be quite good except the ring around the first image, which I do not know what it is, if someone could explain me I would be grateful. My guess is that most likely is a result of bad calibration? Also, in the `initUndistortRectifyMap()` I am using the big resolution sensor's size, otherwise I am getting something completely wrong, I do not understand that as well if someone could explain.

Now if I resize the big resolution image before any calibration (no cropping applied) I get much better results:

[image]
[image]

of course as you can see due to the aspect ratio the images are quite different.

---

**Question 2**

So again continuing from question 1 what is the proper way to go, can I use the images in their initial size or I should resize them, should I apply also cropping? What am I doing wrong in the procedure?

---

---

**Question 3**

Considering that I will manage to obtain the two views after calibration/undistortion/rectification how I do overlay them? I have I have both rgb and depth images, cameraMatric and distCoeffs from both sensors and R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q matrices. I read that I can use cv::projectPoints but I couldn't find an example. I would appreciate if someone cold give me some hints.

Thanks in advance.

p.s. I can provide some code if it is necessary, it is a bit messy for the moment but still if it helps no problem by me.